# Hashing Performances

Tags: performance, hash, time, addition, contains

I am studying for a test and in the study sheet it asks about the Performances of hashing it asks things such as

```
Add
Remove
Search / Contains
Space vs Time
Applications where it makes sense
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: how do i do each with hashing

Comment: The only person that can (hopefully) give you the appropriate hints for your test is the one that wrote the study sheet. Good luck for your test.

Comment: Hashing means Hash tables or text Hashing algo? I think you are asking about first one.

Comment: Yes I do mean Hash tables

Answer (score 0):

Performance of Hashing means analysis of how various data structures using hash technique.

For finding out of performance of hashing, first find out which are available data structures which use hashing. Example could be hash tables, hash maps, hash trees etc.

After that have a round of performance testing for below operations on each of data structure.

1. Add an element
2. Remove
3. Search

Find out Time and space complexity for each operation and each data structure.

After that you will quite a good idea of where you can use which data structure or if a given a requirement you will be able to find out which data structure will be performance efficient.

Hope this helps and clears your doubts :)